# Not able to hit a Servlet in Struts 2

Tags: java, servlets, struts2, xml-configuration

In my Struts2 application, I am trying to include a Servlet that would handle Ajax  requests. I have included the `excludePattern` in `struts.xml` and mapped the servlet in `web.xml`. I'm still not able to hit the Servlet. Here are my XML files.

**`Struts.xml`:**

```
<struts>
 <constant name="struts.devMode" value="true" />
 <constant name="struts.action.excludePattern" value="/ajaxservlet"/>
 <package name="helloworld" extends="struts-default">
   <action name="loginAction" class="controller.loginAction" method="execute">
     <result name="success">home.jsp</result>
     <result name="error">index.jsp</result>
   </action>
 </package>
</struts>
```

**And this is in my `web.xml`:**

```
<filter>
  <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
  <filter-class>
     org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter
  </filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
  <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>control</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>controller.control</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>  
    <servlet-name>control</servlet-name>  
    <url-pattern>/ajaxservlet</url-pattern>  
</servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: any specific reason to use servlet and not standard Struts2 actions?

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the mapping for the servlet

```
<servlet>
  <servlet-name>control</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>controller.control</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>control</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/ajaxservlet/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

and modify the struts configuration accordingly

```
<constant name="struts.action.excludePattern" value="/ajaxservlet/?.*"/>
```